# CFA model with systematic temporal correlation between measures

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, autoregressive, psychometrics, confirmatory-factor, item-response-theory

I'm looking to fit CFA models to data in the case where measures have systematic temporal correlations between them. I'm familiar with autoregressive approaches, such as those described on [Dave Kenny's website](http://davidakenny.net/cm/ar.htm).

However, whereas this approach is using the same measures at two different time points, I'm thinking of data where underlying model is..

```
Congeneric model with two factors, A and B. 
The six measures for these two factors are a_1, a_2, .., a_m, and b_1, b_2, .., b_m.

N observations with 2M measures each.
Measures are taken in the same random temporal order for each observation
```

Suppose that correlations between errors for each pair of measures are a function of how close they are in time. In the case where only adjacent measures in time are correlated, then I should be able to specify a model with a path diagram where measures are ordered in time like..

[image]

where in this case, $c_1$ is a free parameter that measures the impact of putting measures near in time. However, extending out from this case, I'm interested in using an additional free parameter for correlating errors of items that are say, two points in time apart, and so on. Alternatively, I could see correlating errors using the covariance matrix of an AR(n) model, to reduce free parameters.

Does this type of model have a name in either psychometrics or other fields? It seems like this case must have been studied in the past, but I'm at a loss for finding it (other than autoregressive models that are often used in longitudinal research).

Comment: Longitudinal structural equation model would be one term for a model of this type. Rasch or IRT models could be another. Longitudinal mixed effects model could be a third. Here's a paper that uses some of these terms:  *Analysis of a Complex Longitudinal Health Related Quality of Life Data by a Mixed Logistic Model* and here's a link to a gated copy  http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-12694-4_19

Comment: Thanks--I'll have to take a look at it. The big point of separation between the model I laid out and SEMs for longitudinal designs is that they're often the same measures at different points in time, whereas here, time and measurement would be confounded (and each measure occurs once). I'm sure there's a longitudinal SEM with these characteristics lurking around somewhere though...